# Setup Devise to only allow editing of own records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I've got Devise working in my Rails app but I can't figure out how to now lock it down so a user can only edit their own record in the users table AND in tables belonging to the user.

What am I missing here? Is this done in the controller or the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a helper in application_controller for `current_user` and remove the use of `User.find`

The simplest way of creating an *authorization* is with a boolean flag (admin true/false). For other simple solutions are cancan, as mentioned by Yannis or [easy_roles](http://github.com/platform45/easy_roles) KISS is recommend to start with. You may implement the edit action like this

```
def edit
 if current_user.is_admin?
   User.find(params[:id])
 else
    current_user
 end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
  UserSession.find
end
```

To limit access by the user, like a user having his/hers own tasks, do this.

```
def index
  @tasks = current_user.tasks
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Devise is an authentication solution. You now need an authorization system. Have a look to Ryan Bates CanCan ([github](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan), [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)).