# Using Devise, how do I make it so that a user can only edit/view items belonging to them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I've been struggling with this for a while now, so I thought I'd ask the experts.

I am trying to make it so that Users can only edit/view Items that they have created using Devise.

I have Users set up and working well. Items are being created with a user associated with them and I can verify this via rails console.

```
def create
 @item = Item.new(params[:item])
 @item.user = current_user
end
```

What I am trying to do now is to make it so that once logged in, users can only see the items that they have created, and no others.

In my Items controller have tried replacing:

```
def index
 @items = Items.all
end
```

with

```
def index
 @items = current_user.Items.find(params[:id])
end
```

but this doens't seem to work for me and I get

```
undefined method `Items' for #<User:0x007fdf3ea847e0>
```

Can anyone offer any advice as to what to try next?

Thanks so much.

Comment: devise is a authentication framework/gem. What you are looking for is a authorization gem. I think cancan is the current goto for that but there are quite a few more around. Most work fine with warden/devise

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup Devise to only allow editing of own records?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966344/setup-devise-to-only-allow-editing-of-own-records)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Maybe I`m old school but I would not use current_user to find records, only to verify permissions. I would use the primary key relationships directly (they don't change):

   `@items = Item.find(:all, :conditions => { :user_id => current_user[:id] }`

or

```
@items = Item.find_all_by_user_id current_user[:id]
```

As for setting permissions, devise actually doesn`t let you do that BUT there is the excellent supplement called Cancan, you should definitely look into it. With Cancan, you will have an ability.rb class that will define your permissions. What you are looking for then becomes:

```
class Ability
  can [:read, :show, :edit, :update, :delete, :destroy], Item do |item|
    item.user_id == user.id
  end

  # or
  can :manage, Item do |item|
    item.user_id == user.id
  end
end
```

reading the Cancan docs would clarify the code above.

Comment: This worked a treat. I also found a really great series on ThinkVitamin which gave me the rest of the bits and pieces that I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is really close…

`current_user` is an "instance" of the `User` class.

What you want to do is use the association from the user instance, which is a special method applied to every user—"`items`". (If the `Item` class also has a `belongs_to :user` it'll have a method called `user` as well)

You want `current_user.items.find(params[:id])`

Also, when you create it, you could also use `current_user.items.create(params[:item])`

Comment: Ok, thanks Ben. I've tried that. Now I'm getting

    Couldn't find Item without an ID

It feels like I'm so darn close.

Comment: Actually with the latest version of ```CanCan```, ```current_user.items``` will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question, I think you might want to check out an authorization library - like CanCan to do this.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

It works pretty slick to handle permission type things like this. Many people use this library in conjunction with Devise.

Comment: Thanks for that - I did try CanCan at one point, but I'm pretty green, so the added complexity blew my mind. I'm getting very close now (can restrict editing/viewing), so I'm down to just making it so that a user can only view their own items in the index view.